# Youtube feed block

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm trying to get my youtube channel feed on my drupal 7 website. I searched a lot on the internet, but most are old answers that doesn't work anymore.
Modules like Youtube Channel Block, ... Even the iframe solutions doesn't work anymore.

My question is simple:
How can I get my youtube channel feed on a page / block without scripting a whole module with the Youtube API? It doesn't have to play on the page/block. I don't want to add the video's one by one..

Answer (score 0):

Use the following URL to access feeds:

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=YOUR_YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_NUMBER
```